# CSP issue, strict policy applied but cannot find where it is defined

Tags: google-chrome, tomcat, wicket, content-security-policy

I wrote a Java WebApp using Tomcat Version 9.0.69 and Wicket 9.12.0 plus Chrome Version 109.0.5414.75 for display, but CSP (Content-Security-Policy) totally messes up the display with a bunch of "Refused to [load the stylesheet/script '' | apply inline style] because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: ...".

I tried to use HTML metas like "", it failed.

I tried to configure CSP inside Tomcat config, it failed too.

The only way right now I can see my web application properly is by using a Chrome plugin to disable CSP for the display tab.

I would like to fix this issue at the source, where is strict CSP policy defined here, Tomcat, Wicket, or Chrome?

I tried to fix CSP in HTML metas and Tomcat config, no effect.
Only disabling CSP in Chrome with a plugin worked to nullify CSP effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some CSP related settings are defined in Wicket.
If you use the quickstart Maven archetype then they are in [WicketApplication.java](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/archetypes/quickstart/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/java/WicketApplication.java#L34-L37)

You could disable them by replacing these lines with:

```
getCspSettings().blocking().disabled();
```

Comment: Many thanks, that was it (for info last method is ".disabled();", not ".disable();").
It totally blows my mind that ultra strict CSP restrictions are defined in source code of the application server itself, I was expecting them in some config file instead.

Comment: This is how it works! I've updated the answer. You can mark it as `accepted` if you like.